# When I use button to show sheet, after the sheet is pulled down, it is automatically displayed again

Tags: button, swiftui

When I use button to show sheet, after the sheet is pulled down, it is automatically displayed again.

Add argument ondismiss

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {self.showEditorInfo.toggle()}) {
        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showEditorInfo, onDismiss: {self.showEditorInfo.toggle()}) {
        Text("123")
    })
}
```

Comment: Offhand, your `sheet` modifier looks... wrong to me. What version of `Xcode` are you using? Also, why are you toggling `showEditorInfo` in `onDismiss`? I'm thinking the latter is why things are happening (and to test things, try two things, taking it completely out and instead of `toggle()` explicitly set it to `false). But first, make sure you have the latest beta version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

When the sheet gets pulled down your view gets redrawn and because showEditorInfo is true the sheet gets presented again. Make sure you reset the value in onDismiss:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showEditorInfo,
       onDismiss: { self.showEditorInfo = false }) {
           Text("123")
    }
```

You may want to pass showEditorInfo as a binding into the next view so that you can dismiss it programatically. That's why it is important to set the value to false in onDismiss and not toggle it.

Answer (score -1):

There are two unrelated issues here: the first is the `toggle()` in your `onDismiss` handler, the second appears to be a Simulator bug with an easy workaround.

1. `isPresenting` takes a *binding*  as an argument, which tells you the sheet will react to changes in `showEditorInfo`'s value but ***also*** that it'll modify that value to reflect the state of the UI. When you drag down on the sheet to dismiss it, `showEditorInfo` is automatically set to false. In your code, you were toggling it back to true.
2. After addressing #1, your issue is fixed on devices  but still occurs in the Simulator. The cause *seems to be* that your sheet is attached to the `Button` in your `navigationBarItems`. If you put the sheet on the `NavigationView` itself, or literally anywhere except the `Button`, it behaves as expected in the Simulator.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showEditorInfo = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("ContentView")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showEditorInfo.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditorInfo) {
            Text("Sheet")
        }
    }
}
```